# Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 not working

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have been attempting to follow this post to enable attribute routing in OData 8.0.10:

[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Core OData 8.0 RC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/#:%7E:text=Attribute%20routing%20is%20how%20Web,such%20as%20RouteAttribute%2C%20HttpGetAttribute%20etc.)

During development of v8 ODataRouteAttribute and ODataRoutePrefixAttribute have been removed and routing is supposed to follow regular ASP.NET Core attribute routing, however I cannot get this to work as described.

I register OData as follows:

```
// build edm:
model = builder.EntitySet<Stuff.PersonProfile>("personProfiles");
    

// startup.cs
odataOptions.Count().Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().SetMaxTop(3).AddRouteComponents("", model)

// person profiles controller:
[Route("personProfiles")]
public class PersonProfilesController : ODataController
{

     [HttpGet("Person")]
     IActionResult GetPerson(ODataQueryOptions<Stuff.PersonProfileService.Models.PersonProfile> options)
     {


     }
}
```

This creates the endpoint correctly and I can reach it:

```
APIStuff.Controllers.PersonProfilesController.GetPerson (Stuff.API) 
GET personProfiles/Person
```

However no OData endpoint mapping is created. If I remove the attribute route on the GetPerson method, then it DOES. i.e.: I get OData returned in the payload of the personProfiles endpoint that it creates.

It appears this was possible in the 8.0 preview as described in the following:

[Routing in ASP NET Core 8.0 Preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/routing-in-asp-net-core-8-0-preview/)

Where clearly there are examples of using attribute routing on the controller and the method. e.g.:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Customers({id})")]
public class AnyControllerNameHereController : ODataController
{
    [ODataRoute("Address")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAddress(int id)
    {
        //......
    }

    [ODataRoute("Address/City")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCity(int id)
    {
        //......
    }
}
```

I can only assume this has been removed or I am missing a very big elephant in the room.

Answer (score 0):

Since 8.0 RC, attribute routing is changed to use [Route] and [HttpGet], etc

From your description, ‘personProfiles’ is an entity set, and “Person” looks like a property defined by the type of “personProfiles”, right?

If that’s the case, based on OData spec, you should query a property from an entity (a single entity). It means you should specify the key/id.

You can put the key in [Route] or in [HttpGet].

```
// person profiles controller:
[Route("personProfiles")]
public class PersonProfilesController : ODataController
{

     [HttpGet("{key}/Person")] // this will generater route as:  ‘personProfiles/{key}/Person’.   It’s key as segment.
     IActionResult GetPerson(ODataQueryOptions<Stuff.PersonProfileService.Models.PersonProfile> options)
     {
     }
}


// person profiles controller:
[Route("personProfiles({key})")] // this will generater route as:  ‘personProfiles({key})/Person’.  It’s key in parenthesis. 
public class PersonProfilesController : ODataController
{

     [HttpGet("Person")] 
     IActionResult GetPerson(ODataQueryOptions<Stuff.PersonProfileService.Models.PersonProfile> options)
     {
     }
}
```

```
Thanks,
-Sam
```

Comment: Correct, personProfiles is an entity set, and also the name of the controller, as I believe that is the OData convention?
What I require is a method on personProfiles called person, i.e.:
personProfiles/person
WITHOUT a key. i.e.: a regular get method. This is because it will get the currently authenticated user. I require OData $select on this endpoint to limit the return payload.